# smile detection when running the code of NN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I have an error when I launch the training of the model indicating the existence of more than one element is ambiguous

I try to detect the smile of faces from RGB images by CNN using python and KERAS

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

rom imutils import paths
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.utils import img_to_array
data = []
labels = []

imagePaths = list(paths.list_images("/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/SMILEs"))

for imagePath in sorted(list(paths.list_images("/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/SMILEs"))):
 # load the image, pre-process it, and store it in the data list
  image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
  image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  image = imutils.resize(image, width=28)
  image = img_to_array(image)
  data.append(image)
# extract the class label from the image path and update the labels list
  label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-3]
  label = "smiling" if label == "positives" else "not_smiling"
  labels.append(label)

data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)

le = LabelEncoder().fit(labels)
labels = np_utils.to_categorical(le.transform(labels), 2)

classTotals = labels.sum(axis=0)
classWeight = classTotals.max() / classTotals

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data,labels, test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

class LeNet:
  def build(width, height, depth, classes):
    model = Sequential()
    inputShape = (height, width, depth)
    #if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
        #inputShape = (depth, height, width)

  # premiere couche de CONV==>RELU==>POOL:
    model.add(Conv2D(20, (5, 5), padding="same",input_shape=inputShape))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

  # Deuxieme couche CONV==>RELU==>POOL: 
    model.add(Conv2D(50, (5, 5), padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# La couche fully connected et d'applatissement: 
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(500))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))

    model.add(Dense(classes))
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))
    return model

model = LeNet.build(28, 28, 1,2)


from tensorflow import keras
print("[INFO] compiling model...")
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="adam",metrics=['accuracy'])

print("[INFO] training network...")
H = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY),class_weight=classWeight, batch_size=64, epochs=15, verbose=1)
```

and here is the error displayed
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Which line produces this error message?

Comment: this line of code generates this error :  H = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY),class_weight=classWeight, batch_size=64, epochs=15, verbose=1)